# MpAndroidChart: dashed line relating to data count

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to show chart with dashed line in my application. I am using MpAndroidChart to achieve it. It works, but when data contains too much values, it works incorrectly. For example:

1. Only 7 values on chart:

[image: only 7 values on chart]

2. Over 500 values:

[image: > 500 values]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The library behaves as expected. The problem is that you are providing too many data points so that the curve overlaps itself (and thus the dashing is displayed as in your image).

Depending on your use case I can suggest the following solutions:

1. Reduce the line width (probably not sufficient in your case)
2. Smooth the data points (on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html) page an overview of possible methods is given)

Comment: I am replace second picture in question. It shown like a simple line. I think that is not correct behaviour... Also I can't change reduce data points count, because user can check one of all by click.

Comment: Could you please add an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Can you reproduce the behaviour even with a straight line? Even if the user can choose the data points you could additionally apply smoothing to the values before displaying them (probably depending on the zoom level).